# Howto get groups by repeated pattern with qantizer in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group, multiple-matches

I have the following string:

```
(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I want to get out all comma separated values by a regular expression.

If I put away the brackets

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

and use the following regular expression:

```
([^,]),?
```

I get out one match as well as one group for each comma separated value.

But if I want to do with concluding brackets using the regular expression:

```
\((([^,]),?)+\)
```

I still get only one match and one group. The group contains only the last comma separated value.

I tried also with group captures like:

```
(?:....)
(...?)
(...)?
```

but I cannot get out the comma separated values by regular expression groups.

How can I do this, when the comma separated values are enclosed in brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. Using C# you can use the property Captures in the Match Collection.

Using Regex:

```
\((([^,]),?)+\)
```

Do:

```
        string text = "(a,b,c,d,e)";
        Regex rgx = new Regex("\\((([^,]),?)+\\)");
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(text);
```

Then you have 1 item with the following 3 groups in the matchcollection:

```
[0]: \((([^,]),?)+\) => (a,b,c,d,e)
[1]: ([^,]),?+ => value and optional comma, eg. a, or b, or e
[2]: [^,] => value only, eg. a or b or ...
```

The list captures within the group stores each extracted value by quantizer. So use group [2] and captures to get out all the values.

So the solution is:

```
        string text = "(a,b,c,d,e)";
        Regex rgx = new Regex("\\((([^,]),?)+\\)");
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(text);

        //now get out the captured calues
        CaptureCollection captures = matches[0].Groups[2].Captures;

        //and extract them to list
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Capture capture in captures)
        {
            values.Add(capture.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general that's how repeated groups work - you don't have separate groups, just the last one. If you want to separate values between commas, it's better to use string functions available in your programming language to first strip brackets and then split string on commas.

For example in Ruby:

```
 [10] pry(main)> '(a,b,c,d,e,f)'.gsub(/[()]/,'').split(',')
 # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```